# Specify files to merge with MSBuild.ILMerge.Task

Tags: c#, msbuild, ilmerge

I have a solution which creates multiple .dll and .exe files. I now want to merge some .dll files with the executables. I discovered the MSBuild.ILMerge.Task NuGet package, which by default merges all .dll files into the executable. This is working fine.

But i only want to include some .dll files, since others are shared between multiple executables. I had a look at ILMerge.props but there is no way to specify which .dll files are merged.

How can i specify the input files when using the MSBuild.ILMerge.Task package?

Answer (score 5):

It merges dlls marked "copy local"; to exclude dll from the merge, set its copy local to false.
Beware: from 1.05 on, the merge is by default transitive, so set copy local to false in referenced projects, too.